# Ajax запрос выполняется несколько раз при быстром нажатии

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня выполняется форма через ajax запрос, если быстро кликнуть по кнопке сабмита формы несколько раз, то форма сработает столько, сколько нажал.

Comment: И это логично. Прячь или дизейбли кнопку после нажатия. В колбеке показывай/активируй обратно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в функции сабмита делать кнопку `disabled`

```
function onSubmit() {
   btn.disabled = true
   ...
}
```

Или еще как вариант делать какой нибудь спиннер